# VSCode arrow select mode how to get out?

Tags: visual-studio-code, selection

I don't know how did I get into this mode, but whenever I press the arrow buttons, the cursor moved and selected the text it passed. As if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed.

What is it and how to get out?

I have to close and reopen vscode to clear it.

Edit: The mode is entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. Seems an Emacs mark set mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, figured it out. It is Emacs mark set mode. Entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

To exit, **select something first** then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I cannot exit the select mode by Ctrl-g.  This is driving me crazy.  Does anyone have a working solution?  The only way for me to exit the mode is to close the VScode window.  I am a Mac user.

Comment: maybe you can uninstall any emacs related plugins. Ctrl-g should work. I just tried, and I don't need to select anything now. The plugin I have installed is called 'Emacs Friendly Keymap'

Comment: Thanks, your solution started working after I disabled the  Emacs-related plugin.  In my case, the plugin's name was "Emacs Keymap".